# split or remove last character or number from string in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In below code `req.body.urlOfFolder` largest string with `/`, This string last segment I want to split or remove I tried with split (see below code), So how to remove last segement ?

```
 console.log(req.body.urlOfFolder); //  131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988

 var urloffolder =  req.body.urlOfFolder.split('/')[0];
 console.log(urloffolder); // 131 (this output i get)

 console.log(urloffolder); // 131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987 (this output i want)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split by slashes, pop off the last `988` that you don't want, then join again:

```js
const url = '131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988';
const splits = url.split('/');
splits.pop();
const fixedUrl = splits.join('/');
console.log(fixedUrl);
```

Another option would be to use a regular expression:

```js
const url = '131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988';
const fixedUrl = url.match(/\d+(?:\/\d+)+(?=\/\d+$)/)[0];
console.log(fixedUrl);
```

Comment: Wouldn't regex be overkill/slower ?

Comment: On the contrary, the regex is some 6 times faster: https://jsfiddle.net/xwja1kLs/ Could make it even faster with `/.+(?=\/\d+$)/`, but that's unnecessarily imprecise IMO

Comment: You could also just remove the last 4 characters

Comment: It has one issue in case we do not have a special character then it wont return anything.

Answer (score 3):

One more way of doing is using `substr` and `lastIndexOf`

```js
let str = "131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988";

let op = str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf('/'));

console.log(op);
```

**Regex method**

```js
let str = "131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988";

let op = str.match(/.*(?=\/)/g)[0];

console.log(op);
```

Comment: @Ankit always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following using [Array.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```js
let str = "131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988";
let temp = str.split("/"); // create array split by slashes
temp.pop(); // remove the last value 988 in our case
console.log(temp.join("/")); // join the values
```

Comment: @Ankit - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.splice(-1)` or `.pop()` to remove the last element from your split array and then `.join('/')` to rejoin your split string with `/`:

`.split('/')` gives:

```
['131', '131', '980', '981', '982', '983', '984', '985', '986', '987', '988']
```

`.splice(-1)` or `.pop()` turns the above array into (removes last element):

```
['131', '131', '980', '981', '982', '983', '984', '985', '986', '987']
```

`.join('/')` turns the above array into a string:

```
"131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987"
```

```js
const numbers = "131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988"
const numbersArray = numbers.split('/');
numbersArray.splice(-1);

const newNumbers = numbersArray.join('/');
console.log(newNumbers);
```

The above sequences can also be achieved using `.reduce`:

```js
const numbers = "131/131/980/981/982/983/984/985/986/987/988"
const newNumbers = numbers.split('/').reduce((acc, elem, i, arr) => i == arr.length-1 ? acc : acc+'/'+elem);

console.log(newNumbers);
```